# keras Model : input and output configuration

Tags: keras

I saw different inputs and outputs configurations in keras model examples.
However, I couldn't find appropriate documents that explain about input/output specification in details.

For examples:

1) model = Model(inputs = [input1, input2],  ....)

2) model = Model(inputs = [input1] + input2,  ....)

Similarly, for output case as well.

Especially, how are the above 1) and 2) different?

What is use of '+' for?

Comment: I guess in the second approach the `input2` is itself a list and that `+` just concatenates those two lists. Essentially, approaches 1 and 2 are the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your input and outputs in a keras model in both ways.
In case 1) input1 and input2 are just put into a list.

In case 2) input1 with the brackets is also creating a list with itself as an entry. The + operator for list does a concatenation, so by using + a new list is created with input2 appended.

-> It´s the same result